# Tab menu Change multiple content with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get a tab menu by changing more than one div. Like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIa3q.png)

Change the content on the right side is no problem I found many results for that. But how can I switch the headline and the download content below when I click on the buttons on the left side...?
I search for hours on the Internet for this solution, but with no result.

I've got this for the vertical tabs from w3schools:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
}
/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>
<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>
<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<div class="download">
  <h3>DOWNLOAD SOMETHING FOR LONDON</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<div class="download">
  <h3>DOWNLOAD SOMETHING FOR PARIS</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<div class="download">
  <h3>DOWNLOAD SOMETHING FOR TOKYO</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea how to get it. I hope really somebody can help me. I would be very grateful for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below.

```
<div class="download downloadLondon">

var downloads = document.getElementsByClassName("download");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  if (downloads[i].className.indexOf('download'+cityName) >= 0) {
    downloads[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
    downloads[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I think it would be easier if you use jQuery though.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

    var downloads = document.getElementsByClassName("download");
    for (i = 0; i < downloads.length; i++) {
      if (downloads[i].className.indexOf('download'+cityName) >= 0) {
        downloads[i].style.display = "block";
      }
      else{
        downloads[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
}
/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>
<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>
<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<div class="download downloadLondon">
  <h3>DOWNLOAD SOMETHING FOR LONDON</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<div class="download downloadParis">
  <h3>DOWNLOAD SOMETHING FOR PARIS</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<div class="download downloadTokyo">
  <h3>DOWNLOAD SOMETHING FOR TOKYO</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your help! Works awsome! Do you also maybe know why I see all "Download" content (3 divs) when I update the page and when I click on the link it is just the right one?

Comment: What do you mean by see all Download content when updating the page?? Does it show all 3 download divs when refreshing the page?

Comment: @Mitschl try adding <div class="download downloadLondon" style="display:none;"> if you see the 3 download divs on page load.

Comment: I added display: none at the other both divs, and now it works perfectly!
Thanks a lot again! You saved my day! :D